# AddJs / CSS in footer. getCssJsHtml() not working

Tags: javascript, css, footer

I've been looking through a lot of posts on **how to add CSS / JS file in the footer.**

As right now I have followed this path : `page.xml`

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="foot" as="foot" template="page/html/foot.phtml"/>
```

**local.xml**
I did try all the variant, `type/skin_js`, `addJs`, `addItem`

```
<reference name="foot">
    <action method="addJs"><script>lebernard/test.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

**foot.phtml**
Translator script is rendering as normal, so foot.phtml is getting called. I tested it with a string as well.

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getTranslatorScript() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
```

Finally I'm calling in `1column.phtml` (and others) `getChildHtml('foot');`

So I though it was a misplaced JavaScript file since the translator script is called properly. I did put it as follow in :

- `/js/lebernard/test.js`
- `/js/test.js`
- `/skin/[theme]/js/test.js`

All I want is to include a js file in the footer using `local.xml` . I'm on 1.9.0.1.

Comment: I have written the blog for this issue. Refer here: http://blog.rahuldadhich.com/magento-load-css-js-footer/

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is add a JS file inclusion in the footer, the easiest way might be to just put it in a template file. So in your `local.xml` file.

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="core/template" template="my-template-file.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

And then in `my-template-file.phtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php $this->getSkinUrl('js/my-js-file.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: This can be workable, but not very good advice. For example merge scripts will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Local.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <!-- add Custome JS to footer -->   
        <block type="page/html_head" name="footerjs" as="footerjs" template="page/html/footerjs.phtml">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/scripts.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/scripts02.js</name></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

In page/html/footer.phtml add at the bottom

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(footerjs) ?>
```

Create page/html/footerjs.phtml and add this

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
```

one last thing you shouldn't add CSS to the footer only js files

**EDIT:**

After creating footerjs block you can use it on individual section on your site, so if you want load js file only on home page you can do this:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="footerjs">

    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Or only on product pages:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="footerjs">

    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Js library not working becouse footer has default cache enabled. You must to add a block inside the footer block.

```
<reference name="footer"> 
    <block type="core/template" name="customname" as="customname">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/scripts.js</name></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```